# Using UnrankPermutation with Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I want to try and use Maximize with UnrankPermutation to find Costas Arrays (or as close as possible) for a given length l with first two elements l, 1. A permutation array that maximizes the number of unique displacement vectors between each element. However I get an error when I try and run my code.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
l = 10;
p =.
Maximize[
 {a = Join[{l, 1}, UnrankPermutation[p, Range[2, l - 1]]];
  v = Table[
    If[j > i, {(i - j), a[[i]] - a[[j]]}, {0, 0}], {i, 1, l}, {j, 1, 
     l}];
  vFlat = Flatten[v, 1];
  CountDistinct[vFlat],
  0 <= p <= (l! - 1) && Element[p, Integers]
  }, p
 ]

Join::heads: Heads List and UnrankPermutation at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.

Part::partw: Part 3 of Join[{10,1},UnrankPermutation[p,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]] does not exist.
```

The code runs fine outside of Maximize[]

Answer (score 1):

This works in 13.3 on Windows 10 with `NMaximize` instead of `Maximize`.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
l = 10;p =.NMaximize[{a = Join[{l, 1}, UnrankPermutation[p, Range[2, l - 1]]];
v = Table[ If[j > i, {(i - j), a[[i]] - a[[j]]}, {0, 0}], {i, 1, l}, {j, 1, 
l}]; vFlat = Flatten[v, 1];
CountDistinct[vFlat], 0 <= p <= (l! - 1) && Element[p, Integers]},  p]
```

> `{46, {p -> 0}}`

and a lot of warnings, one of those is  "General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details".

Comment: Thanks but when I back check with p=0 I just get CountDistinct[vFlat]=18 instead of 46. So it's not returning the right 'p'